# UIFooterView not showing when using deque Reusable cell with identifier to get UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, uiview

I am trying to add a footer to my UITableView. I was able to do this programmatically by making a new UIView with the desired height and width and setting the tableView's tableFooterView to this view.

However, I want to use a reusable tableView cell as my table footer. I tried to set the property as follows

```
myTable.tableFooterView = myTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("footerCell") as UIView!
```

However, the table View does not show up. I was able to get it working when implementing the tableViewforSection delegate method. However, I realized that I need a table footer and not a section footer, since I'm effectively trying to create a custom last cell for my table that scroll with it.

PS: I checked the identifier for my footer cell in storyboard and it looks correct. I also tried creating a custom class for my custom cell and setting the storyboard cell to be of that type, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Make footerCells `contentView` as `tableFooterView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a cell for your footer, and you're using an array to populate your "regular" cells, then return the array.count + 1 in numberOfRows, and put an if clause in your cellForRowAtIndexPath to check if indexPath.row == array.count. If so, dequeue your footer cell.

Comment: This is actually so simple, I feel stupid for not trying it. However, do you have any idea about why the other method doesn't work?

Comment: @DarvishKamalia I'm not sure why the code you posted doesn't work, other than a table footer view is supposed to be a UIView and the dequeue method returns a UITableViewCell -- casting it to a UIView doesn't make it one.